# How do I refactor compiled LINQ queries?

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, compiled-query

Is it possible to refactor compiled LINQ to SQL queries? Suppose that I have a query with some logic, and I'd like to build onto it. Is it possible to reuse that query?

For example, suppose I have a basic query to get active items:

```
Func<DataContext, IQueryable<Item>> GetActiveItems =
    CompiledQuery.Compile((DataContext context) =>
        context.Items.Where(item => item.IsActive));
```

I'd like to build onto the above expression to make another query. The documentation of [`CompiledQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.data.linq.compiledquery.compile.aspx) indicates that I cannot apply another operator on the result of the compiled delegate. So what is the recommended way of refactoring such expressions?

I think I should be using an `Expression`, but how should it be used? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like PredicateBuilder to help with this:

The Albahari one is simple and works quite well although it's easy to extend or develop you own:
http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Obviously if your query relies on a local method that can't be translated to a SQL expression you'll have to rethink how you do it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. `PredicateBuilder` was not the best fit, but LinqKit's `Expand` method was exactly what I needed. If you could edit your answer to refer to it (preferably with a small example), I'd gladly accept it.